# Google Sheets - Import XML

Tags: xml, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, nav

I have been looking on the internet for this issue and I have seen other people solve this issue but some are still unable to figure this out. I am trying to use the `IMPORTXML` function.

```
=IMPORTXML("http://quotes.morningstar.com/fund/c-header?t=FID215", "//span[@vkey='NAV']")
```

> [Function: IMPORTXML(url, xpath_query, locale)]

I get *'Resource at url not found.'*

All I am trying to do is get the `NAV` for this mutual fund.

Things I have tried:

1. From the morningstar website -> right click -> inspect -> copy XPath
2. Change URL around, tiny URL, etc.

Comment: I copied your exact formula and it works fine. It returns 32.6. Try with another browser or check your network.

Comment: I am using google chrome. I tried it with Edge. The cell still says ''N/A" Error
Resource at url not found. What am I doing wrong?

=IMPORTXML("http://quotes.morningstar.com/fund/c-header?t=FID215", "//span[@vkey='NAV']")

Comment: I copied formula and it behaves same as to @sniperfx20. N/A - Resource at url not found.  There is some Javascript error on page and `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)` returns: Exception: Request failed for http://quotes.morningstar.com returned code 404. Truncated server response: The report is no longer supported.

Answer (score 1):

My Google Apps Script scraping `quotes.morningstar.com` stopped working this week.

A couple of tests show that in Google Apps Script this GET request fails:

```
const url = "https://quotes.morningstar.com/fund/c-header?t=LU0690375182"
const options = { muteHttpExceptions: true};
let fetch = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
Logger.log('result: ' + fetch.getContentText());
Logger.log('code: ' + fetch.getResponseCode());
```

resulting error:

```
result: The report is no longer supported
code: 404
```

The exact same GET request in my browser (or through curl) still works just fine.

The only difference I can think of is the originating IP address for the request.

The GAS request will be coming from a limited set of IP addresses Google uses to host GAS. Possibly someone at Morningstar has added them to a blocklist?